# Set of nodes in every minimum cut of flow graph

Tags: algorithm, network-flow

I'm currently working through exercises to study network flow algorithms, and I'm stuck on a sub-problem I think is necessary to solve one such exercise.

The question:  How does one compute the set of nodes which belong to *every* minimum cut of a flow graph?

Intuitively, if Ford-Fulkerson is used and augmentation paths are chosen so as to have a minimum number of edges, this should give us a cut set of minimal cardinality, but must these nodes be in *every* minimum cut?

If so, I can't seem to prove it.  If not, I don't have any real ideas.  Perhaps finding a mechanism for exchanging edges in the residual graph?

Comment: "but must these nodes be in every minimum cut?" absolutely not.

Comment: Are you sure the problem talks about nodes? A cut is a subset of the edge set.

Comment: The optimal solution to Minimum cut of a graph is the same optimal solution to Maximum flow of the same graph

Comment: As I understand it, a cutset can be defined just as well with nodes.  For example, if we define A = {s} and B = V - {s}, then we implicitly define an s-t cut with capacity equal to the sum of the capacities of edges leaving/entering {s}.  These are the types of cut-sets I am referring to above.

Comment: There is a vertex-cut concept, but it isn't clear how it relates to max-flow. The max-flow min-cut theorem doesn't seem to apply to it.

Comment: @n.m. It relates to max-flow as follows:  Consider some node set S, and some node set V - S.  The arcs from S to V-S define the minimum capacity cut.  This is the basis of Ford-Fulkerson, if we set S to be the set of nodes reachable from the source in the terminating residual graph.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe I've cooked up an appropriate answer:

Claim: Every node which *can* be in a (source-side) min-cut set *must* be source-reachable in flow residual graph Gf returned by max-flow (i.e. Ford-Fulkerson).

Proof: Suppose not.  Then, there exists some u such that there is no s-u path in Fg and is in *some* source-side min-cut set S'.  Since F-F returns the set of nodes reachable by s as its min-cut set (e.g. by BFS), S' is *not* returned by F-F.  This implies u is in T (the sink-side of the min-cut).

We now show that there is no means of transforming S to S' while retaining the min-cut property.  Suppose it were possible.  Then, any algorithm capable of the transformation would need to be able to identify an s-u path to *push* flow from s to u in *some* residual graph.  Note, however, that this is not possible.

Consider any edge (v, w) such that v is in S and w in T.  Since u was not in S, it must be that w is not u (i.e. there is no forward edge from S to u, else it would be in S already).  Then, it must be that u is made accessible to s by adding a forward edge from S to T.  However, this is impossible!  Flow only may be added on reverse edges, by the max-flow/min-cut property.  The claim is then proven.

To solve the problem posted above, we simply compute the set of all nodes which *can* be in a source-side min-cut set (call this set A), then reverse edges and compute the set of all nodes which *can* be in a sink-side min-cut set (call this B), compute the intersection (call this C), and then compute Answer = A - C.  The complexity of this algorithm is the same as F-F, which is to say O(|V|^3).

Please let me know if you find any errors!  Sorry for answering my own question!